# Routing creates multiple location keys for same url in one click

Tags: reactjs, routes, browser-history

Routing is creating multiple history entries for same url. I have defined route as below

```
<Route
  path="/account-manager/carAddition/:profile"
  exact
  render={() => <DetailPage {...this.props} />}
/>
```

It should have created just one history entry.